# How to extract Node ID from a igraph object into a data.frame object in R?

Tags: networking, igraph

I have a igraph object (g3). It comprises of 2 columns from an edgelist - (1) From and (2) To. The values of both columns are "Node IDs" (e.g. 1001).

After calculating Degree Centrality, I wish to export it into a dataframe object. However, only row.names (row numbers) are exported, but I need the Node ID.

How can I export the "Node ID" into the dataframe as well?

```
g3 <- graph_from_data_frame(edgelist, directed = TRUE) 

g3$degree <- degree(g3)                      

centrality <- data.frame(row.names   = g3$name, #I want this to be the Node ID
                         degree      = g3$degree)
```

Output of g3:

```
IGRAPH f24e67d DN-- 27770 352807 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c)
+ edges from f24e67d (vertex names):
 [1] 1001->9304045 1001->9308122 1001->9309097 1001->9311042 1001->9401139 1001->9404151 1001->9407087 1001->9408099
+ ... omitted several edges
```

I tried to use `V(g3)` instead of `g3$name`. However, an error occurs and it does not work as well.

```
centrality <- data.frame(name        = V(g3)$name, 
                         degree      = g3$degree)`
```

The Error is: `Error in data.frame(name = V(g3)$name, degree = g3$degree, : arguments imply differing number of rows: 27770, 0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the fix - just by calling `V(g3)$NodeID` instead of `V(g3)$name`.

```
centrality <- data.frame(name        = V(g3)$NodeID, #instead of V(g3)$name 
                         degree      = g3$degree,
                         closeness   = g3$closeness,
                         betweenness = g3$betweenness,
                         eigenvector = g3$eig,
                         hub = g3$hubs,
                         authority = g3$authorities)
```